# Make beamer-TikZ-animation faster

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {.5,.75,...,20}
{
    \begin{frame}
    \centering
        \transduration{.75}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \useasboundingbox (-1,-2) rectangle (1,1);
                \pgfmathsetmacro\limit{atan(.5/1.5)}
                    \draw[dashed] (0,.5) -- (0,-2);
%                   \pgfmathsetmacro\newangle{(\limit/(360))*2*3.14}
%                   \foreach \x in {0,-10,...,\limit}
%                   {
%                       \pgfmathsetmacro\angle{45*abs(sin(\n r))}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\angle{((e^(-.25*\n)*cos(2*\n r)))*30-90}
                \draw (0,0) -- (\angle:1.5);
            \fill[rotate=\angle] (-.5,0) -- (0,-1) -- (.5,0) -- cycle;
%               \fill[rotate around={(-.5*\angle:(\angle:1.5))}] ([xshift=-.1cm]\angle:1.5) -- ([yshift=-.1cm]\angle:1.5) -- ([xshift=.1cm]\angle:1.5) -- cycle;
            \fill[shift={(\angle:1.5)},red] (90+\angle:.5) -- (270+\angle:.5) -- (\angle:.7) -- cycle;
            \draw[fill=white] (\angle:1.5) circle(.5cm);
%                   }
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
    }
    \begin{frame}{Hallo}
        Hallo, Welt!
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

My question is: How can I encrease the `transduration` speed?

Comment: `\transduration{0}`, this will change slides as fast as your pdf viewer allows

Comment: If you are willing to use acroread (perhaps with Wine on Linux), the animation can be produced with the `animate` package. It provides the `measure` option for testing the animation speed. On my PC I get a max value of 62 frames per second for your example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\transduration{...}` takes as argument the time in seconds each slide is displayed, so the speed of your animation is

[image]

thus to increase the speed, you have to decrease the transduration of the slides. The lowest possible value is `\transduration{0}`, then the duration will just be the time your pdfviewer needs to render the next slide.